# How to be notified of date change in .NET WinForms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to specify a function to be called in my VB.Net 2005 WinForms project at midnight when the system date changes. Is this possible?

I know I could do this by setting a timer by setting the interval to midnight minus the current time, then after the first tick, setting the interval to 24 hours. I was wondering if there was a cleaner, simpler way.

Edit to address comment: I would like to know when the day changes, for example from December 27th to December 28th. I know that the system date/time is continuously changing.

Comment: The system date does not change at midnight. It changes continuously.

Comment: Thanks; I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: The timer will work just fine, cheap and reliable. No point in making it more complicated or look for something cheaper.  It isn't clear why you think you need a better mousetrap.  Beware daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the timer/datediff idea for a couple of reasons.  The most obvious is there isn't always 24 hours in a day and also you will need to restart the app periodically to resync to the clock. (similar to the patriot missle bug).

I would keep it simple and just hit the timer every second or minute or whatever the longest interval you can use for the accuracy required for your app is.

If you need it super accurate and can't trigger an event every millisecond I would hit it every minute until the last minute and then trigger another timer using the datediff.

Comment: Thanks, hitting a timer every minute and then speeding it up at the last minute seems like the best solution. Accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use regular [Windows Task Sheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

This way you write a regular commandline application that works silently in the background when called. It could also exit if it's called before the right time.

**Edit:**
In this case why not use a timer and be done with it?
Even if you got the operating system to tell you the date, it would still be a software implementation (and not much more efficient than a .NET timer), so why not just implement it yourself?

Regarding cleanliness, it can look quite clean - create an event for it if you want.

Comment: I need an already-running application to be notified at midnight, which is necessary for the other functionality of this application. Making a separate program wouldn't work unless you know of a way for an application to raise an event in another application.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a `System.Threading.Timer` with a period of 24 hours and with an initial time which is equal to the `TimeSpan` obtained by subtracting `DateTime.Now` from tomorrow's midnight (`DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`).

Comment: This is pretty much the same solution I already mentioned in my comment, but I will accept the answer if no better solution presents itself.

Comment: Haha :) I read it quickly. Anyway you don't have to set the 24 hours interval AFTER the first tick, but you can do from the constructor. I think it's the simplest way (1 line of code, 2 for more readable code)